# CSS Grid not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sBF2.png)

When I put: **grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);** (This is what shows up)

Grid won't go into 4 columns and 2 rows like I thought it would.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Fairly new to coding so i apologize if I missed something obvious.

HTML code

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">

    <title>Frontend Mentor | [Challenge Name Here]</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <style>
      .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
      .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="main-grid">
      <div class="container upper-left-container">
        <img
          src="images/image-daniel.jpg"
          alt=""
          class"user-photo">
            <div class="user-info">
              <p class="username">Daniel Clifford</p>
              <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
            </div>
            <h1 class="testimony">I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were current, if not more so,
            in the company I joined. I honestly feel I got every  penny’s worth.</h1>
            <p class="test-paragraph"> I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve been looking to make a
        transition and have heard some people who had an amazing experience here. I signed up
        for the free intro course and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter.
        The next 12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since completing
        the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”</p>

    </div>

    <div class="container upper-right-container">
      <img
                    src="images/image-jonathan.jpg"
                    alt=""/
            class="user-photo">
                <div class="user-info">
                    <p class="username">Jonathan Walters</p>
                    <p class="verification">
                        Verified Graduate
                    </p>
                </div>
                <h1 class="testimony">
                    The team was very supportive and kept me motivated
                </h1>
                <p class="test-paragraph">
                    “ I started as a total newbie with virtually no
                    coding skills. I now work as a mobile engineer for
                    a big company. This was one of the best
                    investments I’ve made in myself. ”
                </p>

    <div  class="container bottom-left-container">
      <img
        class="bl-img"
        src="images/image-jeanette.jpg"
        alt="">
          <div class="user-info">
            <p class"username">Jeanette Harmon</p>
            <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
          </div>
          <h1>An overall wonderful and rewarding experience</h1>
          <p>“ Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really enjoy, and make a good living
          while doing something I love. ”</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container bottom-right-container">
      <img
        class="br-img"
        src="images/image-patrick.jpg"
        alt="">
          <div class="user-info">
            <p class="username">Patrick Abrams</p>
            <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
          </div>
          <h1>Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves. Getting guidance from them and
          learning from their experiences was easy.</h1>
          <p>“ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find really refreshing. The program
          gave me the confidence necessary to be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable
          junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You will get the personal attention you need from
          an incredible community of smart and amazing people. ”</p>
    </div>


    <div class="container right-container">
      <img
        class="r-img"
        src="images/image-kira.jpg"
        alt="">
          <div=class="user-info">
            <p class="username">Kira Whittle</p>
            <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
          </div>
          <h1>Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended!  </h1>
          <p>“ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I needed some structure from
          professionals who can help me learn programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former
          student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about the program. The entire curriculum and staff
          did not disappoint. They were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The agile team
          project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my learning to the next level in a way that no tutorial
          could ever have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an example of my developent
          experience. It certainly helped me land a job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers.
          100% recommend! ”</p>
    </div>

  </div>

    <footer class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
      Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
*{
font-family: Barlow Semi Condensed, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0;
  margin;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-size: 13 px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: hsl(210, 46%, 95%);
}

.main-grid{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1150px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

Comment: Open Picture1st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code was totally messed up, You were missing some `=` and have extra `/` in your `<img>` tags. the `CSS` code is having no problem (except the last `}` is missing), the html code has the mistake.

**For Example:**

> <img src="images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="" class"user-photo">

Was missing `=` near class attribute, it will be `class="user-photo"`

and

> <img src="images/image-jonathan.jpg" alt=""/ class="user-photo">

Here there was an extra `/` near alt attribute

**Please refer this code and compare the changes:**

```css
* {
   font-family: Barlow Semi Condensed, sans-serif;
   font-size: 13px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 5px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   text-align: justify;
}

body {
   font-size: 13 px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
   background-color: hsl(210, 46%, 95%);
}

.main-grid {
   display: grid;
   max-width: 1150px;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   column-gap: 15px;
   row-gap: 15px;
}

.user-info {
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.user-info p {
   text-align: center;
}

.user-photo {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
   <div class="container upper-left-container">
      <img src="https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/user.png" alt="" class="user-photo"/>
      <div class="user-info">
         <p class="username">Daniel Clifford</p>
         <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
      </div>
      <h1 class="testimony">
         I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were current, if not more so,in the company I joined. I honestly feel I got every  penny’s worth.
      </h1>
      <p class="test-paragraph"> 
         “ I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve been looking to make a
         transition and have heard some people who had an amazing experience here. I signed up
         for the free intro course and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter.
         The next 12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since completing
         the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="container upper-left-container">
      <img src="https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/user.png" alt="" class="user-photo"/>
      <div class="user-info">
         <p class="username">Jonathan Walters</p>
         <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
      </div>
      <h1 class="testimony">
         The team was very supportive and kept me motivated
      </h1>
      <p class="test-paragraph"> 
         “ I started as a total newbie with virtually no
         coding skills. I now work as a mobile engineer for
         a big company. This was one of the best
         investments I’ve made in myself. ”
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="container upper-left-container">
      <img src="https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/user.png" alt="" class="user-photo"/>
      <div class="user-info">
         <p class="username">Jeanette Harmon</p>
         <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
      </div>
      <h1 class="testimony">
         An overall wonderful and rewarding experience
      </h1>
      <p class="test-paragraph"> 
         “ Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really enjoy, and make a good living
         while doing something I love. ”
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="container upper-left-container">
      <img src="https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/user.png" alt="" class="user-photo"/>
      <div class="user-info">
         <p class="username">Patrick Abrams</p>
         <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
      </div>
      <h1 class="testimony">
         Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves. Getting guidance from them and
         learning from their experiences was easy.
      </h1>
      <p class="test-paragraph"> 
         “ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find really refreshing. The program
         gave me the confidence necessary to be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable
         junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You will get the personal attention you need from
         an incredible community of smart and amazing people. ”
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="container upper-left-container">
      <img src="https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/user.png" alt="" class="user-photo"/>
      <div class="user-info">
         <p class="username">Kira Whittle</p>
         <p class="verification">Verified Graduate</p>
      </div>
      <h1 class="testimony">
         Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended! 
      </h1>
      <p class="test-paragraph"> 
         “ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I needed some structure from
         professionals who can help me learn programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former
         student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about the program. The entire curriculum and staff
         did not disappoint. They were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The agile team
         project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my learning to the next level in a way that no tutorial
         could ever have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an example of my developent
         experience. It certainly helped me land a job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers.
         100% recommend! ”
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have nested 4 of your divs inside of the div with class `upper-right-container`.
So what youve made when you used the `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` is 4 columns, but in the second column you have all the divs nested inside of `upper-right-container`.

I have added a background for each of the 4 columns that you want to create in this link https://codepen.io/enasa/pen/jOMXWpO?editors=1100 , and i have also deleted some of the content inside of your paragraphs just to make everithing simple

To make it clearer if you change 4 by 2 in `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` in the link that i sent you will see that two columns are removed from the preview.

If you replace 4 by 3 you'll see that one column is deleted.

I hope this is clear, if not let me know :)

Also, I am new to coding as well I have just learnt grid 2 days ago;).

Comment: He mentioned 4 columns and 2 rows in the question but in this pen you have created 2 columns and 4 rows.

Comment: i havent created 2 columns and 4 rows, I  just made it easier for him to understand whrere he went wrong.

Comment: he has nested 4 divs inside of one which means that only 2 columns will be created, 1 column with one div and another looooong column with 4 divs one below the other (1 row). I have added grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;  for 2 rows- thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Sometimes he have missed the closing tag